# Camel: How to set the JaasConfig in the property

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, apache-kafka-connect, jaas

I was trying to set the keytabs via Camel and wasn't able to map it to a property similar to Spring.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_client_staticjaas
I was trying to either point the JaasConfig to a file or set individual properties

```json
KafkaClient {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab=true
    storeKey=true
    keyTab="/etc/security/keytabs/kafka_client.keytab"
    principal="kafka-client-1@EXAMPLE.COM";
};
```

Comment: Have you tried using system properties? Framework shouldn't matter

Comment: Would this be something like  
`-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_client_jaas.conf`

if yes, that def. is one option but, was wondering if camel had externalized properties similar to spring for them.

Comment: Not for system properties, no, as those are JVM arguments, not application runtime configs. But, also, spring-camel is a thing, so you can do both. Kafka `sasl.jaas.config` property can also be used